# Unexpected Django ORM behavior

Tags: python, django

I have a function, which must make things according to its name, but it works weird for me.

```
def get_or_create_artists_by_metadata(metadata: Dict[str, str]) -> List[Optional[Artist]]:
    if artists := metadata.get('artist'):
        artists = parse_artists_from_string(artists) # returns list of strings

        try:
            existing = Artist.objects.filter(title__in=artists) # 1
        except Exception as err:
            log.exception('Database error!')
            log.exception(err)

            return []

        new_artists_list = list(set(artists) - set(itertools.chain(*existing.values_list('title'))))

        objs = [Artist(title=artist) for artist in new_artists_list]

        try:
            new_artists = Artist.objects.bulk_create(objs) # 2
        except Exception as err:
            log.exception('Error during artists creating!')

            return [*existing]

        result = [*existing]

        if new_artists: # 3
            result.extend(new_artists)

        return result
    else:
        return []
```

For instance, I have 2 strings in `artists` var.

On the step 1 I have nothing at first, empty QuerySet. Then on the step 2 I create new artists and at the same time I have some entries in `existing` var! So on the step 3 I have true, extend `result`, and there are 4 entries already.

Please, explain me this behavior and how should I manipulate this.

Comment: How do you know there is nothing in step 1?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I debug this via pdb

Answer (score 0):

At first in order to check existence it's better to use `exists()`.

```
existing = Artist.objects.filter(title__in=artists)
existing.exists()  # return True or False
```

If to say about your issue I believe its could be connected to wrong use of `value_list` here:

```
existing.values_list('title')
```

as you will be returned the format of list of tuples like:

```
[('125',), ('126',), ('219',)]
```

So here you compare a list of strings and a list of tuples, that's why it's not removing existing strings.

But you expect this:

```
['125', '126', '219',]
```

So in order to have a list of strings but not a list of tuples you need to add `flat=True`

```
existing.values_list('title', flat=True)
```

And the result of the statement:

```
new_artists_list = list(set(artists) - set(itertools.chain(*existing.values_list('title', flat=True))))
```

will return only strings of ids that are not in use.

Comment: But after `existing.exists()`, if exists something, I must do the same request, and the QuerySet will be to contain result of `bulk_create`

Comment: @ruslankrivoshein yes for your case you can check just if Queryset is empty or not, but in general it's better to check by `exists()` as it's rather fast query. 
Did `flat=True` helped you?

Comment: Yes, `flat` helped, thanks! But it was not the point of my question)